# How can a resource method produce or consume two different MIME types?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

How can this resource method produce `json` or `xml` results ?

Should I parse the request accept header and make an `if/else` branch, or [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey) will do that 
for me  ?

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public String doGetAsXmlOrJson() {
    ...
}
```

An example of how `doGetAsXmlOrJson()` may implemented will nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/gipxf/index.html) states

> The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or
>   representations a resource can produce and send back to the client.

so it doesn't actually tell JAX-RS to produce two content types in the response. It initially acts as an indicator for determining which handler method to use. If you had two `GET`s for the same path, the `@Produces` would help choosing the most appropriate.

In your cast, the method can produce both content type. Which one it eventually produces depends on the `Accept` header in the request.

From the same tutorial

> If a resource class is capable of producing more that one MIME media
>   type, the resource method chosen will correspond to the most
>   acceptable media type as declared by the client. More specifically,
>   the Accept header of the HTTP request declared what is most
>   acceptable.

The fact that you are returning a `String` kind of shows that it's up to your implementation to produce the right content. If instead you returned a Pojo of some sort, I do believe Jersey would use the appropriate conversion tool to produce XML (maybe with JAXB) or JSON (maybe with Jackson).

Comment: Should I parse the request accept header and make an if/else branch ?

Comment: @tarrsalah Yes, that seems appropriate for `String` return type. There should be a `@HeaderParam` for that I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

try this